Progress bar shows no progress until done copying file
I need some guidance.
The progress bar does not move at all in the file managers on my Arch Linux system. It stays at zero until the copy has finished. I have tried Nautilus, Nemo, and Thunar, and they all behave the same.
I have copied big single files to make sure the progress bar stays for longer, but still, no progress is shown - files copy fine though.
I have a Debian system and progress bar shows no problem. Any clue where to look?

Maybe you can just try pacman -Syu, if the behavior spans across multiple file managers it might be due to some buggy shared library they all rely on.

Old bug report for Nautilus, but it seems related to bz2 files specifically.
